# Get Intermediate DMN decisions in execution result

Tags: drools, dmn

I have to create a DMN model with mmore than 50 DMN decisions (structured like a tree) in Business central .I have splitted it in different Decision services to not have a large DMN model (difficult to maintain).
I want to see the results of each Decision (intermediate & final decisions) but using Decision service hide the results of intermediate decisions.

[DMN model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaKm.png)

Is it a way to get the result of Decisions R_0_X_X in the DMN evaluation results?

I got no details for Decisions below R_0 in DMN execution result:

```
        "R_0": {
            "R_0_Eval_agent_bankklantDS": "function R_0_Eval_agent_bankklantDS( input )"
        },
        "R_0_Eval_agent_bankklant": "B",
        "R_1_Voorlopige_eindevaluatie": "green",
        "evaluationResult": "green"
```

Answer (score 1):

> but using Decision service hide the results of intermediate decisions

That is the goal of Decision Service semantic in DMN, it encapsulates some of the logic, as only the `outputDecisions` are available as a result of the invocation, while `encapsulatedDecision` are not to be made available in the results.

I assume you need the "results of intermediate decisions" for debugging information, in that case implementing your own `DMNRuntimeEventListener` is the appropriate strategy:

References:

[https://docs.drools.org/7.74.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#dmn-properties-ref_dmn-models:~:text=org.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.%24LISTENER_NAME](https://docs.drools.org/7.74.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#dmn-properties-ref_dmn-models:%7E:text=org.kie.dmn.runtime.listeners.%24LISTENER_NAME)

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/948a4482b4499efed8c28ce4a626af5f942aa9ad/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-api/src/main/java/org/kie/dmn/api/core/event/DMNRuntimeEventListener.java#L19